# Iphone feedback service returns devicetoken without any space

Tags: apple-push-notifications

While sending push notification,we are sending the device token with each 8 bit separated by space as received from the iphone.But while retreiving the inactive device structure from feedback service(using sandbox account),it is giving back the devicetoken without space(length=64). Will it be returing back without space while using the production account too?

Answer (score 1):

There is no space in production too.

[Apple Feedback Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3)